# How can I reset the value of the background in a jPanel to the original in Java?

Tags: java, swing, background, jpanel

I'm making a dark mode in netbeans using a toggle button, but when i try to reset the background to the original color changing the color to (240,240,240) it's different than the original one.
(240,240,240) is the color of the background but when I change it by code to the same value it's different.

Comment: The background depends on the LAF so you should not be hard coding the background. Instead you need get the background of the panel when you make the frame visible and store that value in a variable. Then you use that variable to reset the panel color. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is create a JFrame with two buttons "Dark Mode" and "Original Mode". When you click the button set the background color. The entire class will be about 20 lines of code. Once you get that working then you fix your real application.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I finally did.